# NASM Procedure used in C. Is it possible to modify the arguments used in a function called in C that is a procedure in NASM?

Tags: c, assembly, linker, parameter-passing, nasm

Basically I want to change the variable `a` that is used in the C code below (without doing `a = add(a, 6);` because I intend to use multiple parameters that need to be changed in different functions that will be used for simulating a CPU in C that is linked with NASM for performing each instruction):

```
//main.c
#include <stdio.h>

extern int add(int a, int b);

int main(void){
    int a = 4;
    printf("%d\n", add(a, 6)); //Prints 10
    printf("%d\n", a);         //Prints 4, I want it to maintain the value
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the assembly code:

```
;add.asm
global add

add:
    mov eax, [esp + 4] ;argument 1
    add eax, [esp + 8] ;argument 2
    ret
```

And I compile it with: `nasm -f elf add.asm ; gcc -m32 main.c add.o ; ./a.out`

The code above is a representation of what I want to achieve.
I was thinking of using macros but for what I've found so far I think it's impossible using nasm.

Comment: Q: Is it possible to modify the arguments?  A: Sure.  Just make sure the arguments you're passing from C are the *SAME* as your asm function is expecting.  I'm guessing that's pretty obvious...  Q: Should I use macros?  A: Why?!?  Q: What arguments do you want for your "add()" function, anyway?  It's unclear from your post.  SUGGESTION: Please update your post, and show us a prototype for the C "add()" function you'd *LIKE* to have.

Comment: @paulsm4 Regarding the purpose behind my question is that I'm simulating a CPU in C that uses NASM to execute each instruction and I'm thinking of using as parameters my registers and flags and I need to modify them accordingly. The code above was used just to demonstrate what I'm trying to do. Additionally, how can I make the arguments from C the same that my function in asm is expecting?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. If you have new information or respond to comments, PLEASE [edit] your question. This is not a forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function to pass a pointer, then modify the value of the pointee:

```
extern int add(int *a, int b);

...

printf("%d\n", add(&a, 6)); //Prints 10
```

In assembly code this means that one extra level of indirection is used.  So the code e.g. looks like this:

```
;add.asm
global add

add:
    mov ecx, [esp + 4] ; pointer to argument 1
    mov eax, [esp + 8] ; argument 2
    add eax, [ecx]     ; *a + b
    mov [ecx], eax     ; *a = *a + b
    ret
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter how the called function is implemented, C or assembler or any other language. As you are giving both argument to the function *by value*, it cannot change the original variables, they are copies.

You need to pass *references*, in C these are the addresses of the variables to change.

Your assembler function simply changes the passed parameter. This is allowed and OK, but it does not affect the variables in the caller. You might like to look at parameters as local function variables.